# Get CPU time on OS X

Tags: c, macos, benchmarking

I need to be able to get the [CPU time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_time) for the current process from inside some C code.

On Linux, I can use [`clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime).  On BSD I can use [`clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_VIRTUAL`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/2/clock_gettime/).  On Windows, [GetProcessTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223.aspx).  What is the OS X alternative?

Comment: Look ***[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428958/getting-cpu-time-in-os-x)***.  Existing, good discussion on this topic.

Comment: I saw that, too.  It doesn't answer my question.  In fact, the title of that question and the contents don't really match—the actual text of the question is more about what to do when there is contention for non-CPU resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- [clock()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/clock.3.html) (standard C)
- [getrusage()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man2/getrusage.2.html) (POSIX)

There's also a Mach API task_info() but it doesn't seem to offer any obvious benefit over the portable alternatives for querying CPU time.